# Not able to create buttons dynamically

Tags: android, button

I have an overlay on my screen which will show some buttons to control the feature. This overlay will have a dynamic list of buttons which will be created based on the number of steps. Example if steps are 3 then 3 button will get created. I have created a LinearLayout inside this buttons will get created. I have created a method which will set all the button attributes, but somehow it's giving me null pointer exception.

In onCreateView I have initialize the buttonArray.

Here is my fragment:

```
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mContext = getActivity();
            gc =  GlobalClass.getInstance(mContext);
            db =  DataBaseHelper.getInstance(mContext);
           sectionButtons = new Button[3];
            /*if(savedInstanceState!=null)
                mVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("visible",false);*/

            manager = SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance(mContext);

            //check wether to play video in cover mode or another mode

              inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_side_by_side, container, false);

        }
```

and onViewCreated() I am calling my method addSections():

```
// show overlay with buttons in onTouch
        parentLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (!mVisible) {
                        overLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        addSections(3);
                        mVisible = true;
                    } else {
                        overLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mVisible = false;

                    }


                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Method:

```
 public void addSections(int numOfSection){
        if(numOfSection==0)
            return;
        else {

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfSection; i++) {
                //set the properties for button

                sectionButtons[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
                sectionButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_button);
                sectionButtons[i].setText("Section "+i+"");
                sectionButtons[i].setId(i);

                //add button to the layout
                mSectionLayout.addView(sectionButtons[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

mSectionLayout is my parent LinearLayout. While debugging I found my sectionButtons is not showing null but while setting the attributes it's throwing nullPointer exception.

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: Furthermore...you initialize an array without adding something to it. Did you forget to post something or is the array empty? This would cause the NullPointer.

Comment: @kAliert can you tell me what I have forgot?

Comment: In your posted example, you are initializing this array: `sectionButtons = new Button[3];`. But i cant see where you fill this array with buttons. In the `addSections` method you are trying to get a button from an index. But is the array filled or is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

**Create Dynamic Buttons and attach with the Layout**

You can easily create the dynamic button by the following way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText("Text View ");
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                layout.addView(textView, p);

                Button buttonView = new Button(this);
                buttonView.setText("Button");
                buttonView.setOnClickListener(mThisButtonListener);
                layout.addView(buttonView, p);

        }
        private OnClickListener mThisButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
    }
```

Using this code, you easily generate a list of buttons on the layout. 
Happy coding